# FreeMarker ordering lines with #macro and #nested

Tags: freemarker

I'm trying to create a macro to alphabetically order a section of lines:

```
<#order_lines>
import B
import A
</#order_lines>
```

This should output

```
import A
import B
```

The way I try to implement:

```
<#macro order_lines>
${myUtil.orderLines(<#nested>)}
</#macro>
```

There's a problem with the macro; syntax error at '<#nested>'

```
Encountered "<", but was expecting one of: ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign it to a variable:

```
<#macro order_lines>
<#local x><#nested></#local>
${myUtil.orderLines(x)}
</#macro>
```

Another option is to imlement [TemplateDirectiveModel](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/pgui_datamodel_directive.html) and use it the same way you would use a macro.

Comment: Should be `<#local x><#nested></#local>`, as that doesn't pollute the top-level namespace.

Comment: Another alternative is implementing `TemplateDirectiveModel`; such a value can be called directly similarly to a macro: `<@order_lines>...</@order_lines>`.